# Vue: replacing data object entierly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I know that if I want to add a property to a data object, I use `Vue.set()`.  I did this in my `created()` lifecycle method ... a new field will be added to the `myObject`.  But what about if I wanted to make an api call and completely replace the existing data object of `myObject`?  Can I do what I am doing in `updateMore()` method or is there another way to handle this?

```
data() {
   return {
      myObject: {}
   }
},
async created() {
     let apiData = await axios.get('http://myurl.com');
     this.$set(this.myObject, 'name', apiData.name);
},
methods: {
   updateMore() {
       let moreAPIData = await axios.get('http://myurl.com');

       // will this completely override `myObject` with `moreAPIData` and still be reactive? 
       this.myObject = moreAPIData;
   }
}
```

Comment: According to [this Vue Forum post](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/cant-get-created-hook-to-work-when-its-async/28604) async doesn't work with 'created()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

This assignment of a new object is fine. Vue reactivity issues occurs when you add a new key to an object, because the object is the same, what changed was its content. Javascript compares objects by its address, so if I do

```
new MyClass() === new MyClass()
```

it returns false, because, even if they have the same content, they have different addresses.

To conclude, when you set a whole new object, Vue is able to track the difference, but when you change the content of one key, it can't.

**Full boring text**

You can read the whole documentation about reactivity in Vue [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Comment: Would I be able to do this `this.myObject = {...moreAPIData, ...this.myObject}`  ...use the spread operator to set `myObject` to  the `myObject` properties and `moreAPIData`  combined?.... or is that technically considered adding a new key?

Comment: Notice that 'this.myObject' is a whole new object now, so reactivity ;) . It is also worth noting that depending on the depth of the object, spread operator might not be enough, requiring a 'deep clone' to remove the reference to nested objects.